# indexed_search Multidomain (TYPO3 9 LTS)

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, tx-indexed-search

There is a multidomain setup (domains next to each other on the same level), each domain has their own search page and configuration. I've tried...

```
plugin.tx_indexedsearch.settings.rootPidList = 3
```

...to get the search results limited to the domains pagetree only. But as soon as using rootPidList, there are no results at all any more. Then i've tried...

```
plugin.tx_indexedsearch.settings.defaultOptions.sections = rl1_3
```

...and this seems to work correctly to limit the results to the pagetree (below page id 3).

So what is "rootPidList" ment to be used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comment in the code ([typo3/sysext/indexed_search/Classes/Controller/SearchController.php, Line 232](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/indexed_search/Classes/Controller/SearchController.php#L232)):

> Setting the list of root PIDs for the search. Notice, these page IDs MUST have a TypoScript template with root flag on them!
>
> Basically this list is used to select on the "rl0" field and page ids are registered as "rl0" only if a TypoScript template record with root flag is there.
>
> This happens AFTER the use of $this->searchRootPageIdList above because the above will then fetch the menu for the CURRENT site - regardless of this kind of searching here. Thus a general search will lookup in the WHOLE database while a specific section search will take the current sections.

In a multi domain setup we have set `rootPidList` to the overall root page (in this case id=457).

`defaultOptions.sections` is set like this:

`defaultOptions.sections=rl{$customer_theme.search.level}_{$customer_theme.root}`

`{$customer_theme.search.level}` is set to 1 or 2 depending on the availability of more than one language per country.
`{$customer_theme.root}` is the root page (marked by the root page flag).

e.g. for Indonesia (english) we use level = 2 and root = 12947.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this great explanation!